# Why is screen resolution not equal to screen width (CSS)?

Tags: css, windows

I'm trying to create a responsive website, but something odd is happening. If I go to screen-settings on my laptop I get a resolution of 1920x1080, but (by some trial and error approach) I figured out that my css-width is 1280px.

1. What is the relation between the screen width and screen resolution?
2. How do I find the correct width another time (say on another laptop) i.e the 1280px when I cannot rely on the resolution as width?

Comment: Did you insert the viewport meta tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Not the "initial-scale" but else yes :)